# Derivatives wrt order of MacDonald function

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions

I'm looking for a closed-form expression for 
$$
\left.\left[\frac{\partial^n}{\partial \nu^n}K_{\nu}(z)\right]\right|_{\nu=\pm\tfrac{1}{2}},\;\;n\ge1
$$
where $K_{\nu}(z)$ denotes the [MacDonald function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.25). In case it matters, I'm interested only in the case when $z>0$. For $n=1$, the answer is as follows:
$$
\left.\frac{\partial\mathop{K_{\nu}}\nolimits\!\left(x\right)}{\partial\nu}%
\right|_{\nu=\pm\frac{1}{2}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}\mathop{E_{1}}\nolimits%
\!\left(2x\right)e^{x},
$$
cf. http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.38.E7. Here $E_1$ denotes the exponential integral.

What about higher-order derivatives $(n\ge2)$?

**Update:** The question is related to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4019/derivate-bessel-function-with-respect-to-order) question.